# Require fails with a TypeError 'is not a class' when running rake via RubyGems wrapper

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a ruby extension written in C++, `P4`, and it seems to generally work:

- I can run `irb -Ilib` and then `require 'P4'`, and use it
- I can execute tests via rake by accessing the shell script in the `bin` folder of the rake gem, e.g., `${GEM_HOME}/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake test`

*however*, when I access rake via the RubyGems wrapper in my path, e.g., `rake test`, I get this `TypeError`

```
/Users/tjuricek/dev/p4ruby/lib/P4.rb:38:in `require': P4 is not a class (TypeError)
        from /Users/tjuricek/dev/p4ruby/lib/P4.rb:38:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/tjuricek/dev/p4ruby/test/testlib.rb:31:in `require'
        from /Users/tjuricek/dev/p4ruby/test/testlib.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/tjuricek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:15:in `require'
        from /Users/tjuricek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:15:in `block in <main>'
        from /Users/tjuricek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `select'
        from /Users/tjuricek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `<main>'
rake aborted!
```

Then it pops out the ruby command that "failed". If I copy and paste that command and run it, it works.

What I've noticed is that RubyGems creates a fairly simple wrapper script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby_executable_hooks
#
# This file was generated by RubyGems.
#
# The application 'rake' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'rubygems'

version = ">= 0"

if ARGV.first
  str = ARGV.first
  str = str.dup.force_encoding("BINARY") if str.respond_to? :force_encoding
  if str =~ /\A_(.*)_\z/ and Gem::Version.correct?($1) then
    version = $1
    ARGV.shift
  end
end

gem 'rake', version
load Gem.bin_path('rake', 'rake', version)
```

I'm *guessing* that the last line, `load Gem.bin_path...` has triggered some kind of misconfiguration of my part in creating my extension, but I have no idea what that would be.

Does anyone have ideas on what might cause `require` to fail only when run under the RubyGems wrapper?

Answer (score 3):

OK, the way to debug this is to go into a line where you load the file:

```
require 'P4.so'
```

And see if it's defined:

```
puts "P4 #{P4.class}"
require 'P4.so'
```

In this case, when running under rake directly, it loaded the `.gemspec` which pulled in a version definition that created (incorrectly, in my case) a `P4` module:

```
module P4
  version = VERSION = '3000.0.0.pre0'
end
```

So, for me the fix included:

1. Changing `module P4` to `class P4`
2. Requiring the version definition before my `require 'P4.so'` statement, typically: `require_relative 'P4/version'`
3. Not defining the class in my C++ extension code, but loading it and extending the one defined in my version file:

   // Ensure the class has been defined by the version specification
   cP4 = rb_path2class("P4");